# How to Align Bootstrap thumbnails horizontally

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I know this is a silly question but Can someone please tell me how can I arrange `Bootstrap thumbnails` horizontally?

Currently the thumbnails are placed vertically (one below the other).

This is my code snippet for the two thumbnails.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="photos/square.png" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3 style="font-size:16px;position:relative;left:35px;top:-27px;font-family:Myriad Pro;color:white;">Software Name</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-ok" role="button">Read More</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="photos/square.png" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3 style="font-size:16px;position:relative;left:35px;top:-27px;font-family:Myriad Pro;color:white;">Software Name</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-ok" role="button">Read More</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here's s screenshot how it is placed.

[image]

Comment: You are putting your thumbnails in different `row`s. Just remove the second `<div class="row">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the second row and add some CSS to give the thumbnails a fixed width and inline flow.

**EDIT**: Added some CSS to achieve the background colors without an image.

```css
.thumbnail {
    border:1px black solid;
    width:180px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:white;
    height:300px;
  }
  .green-space {
    margin:3px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:#3ECE30;
  }
  .green-space .empty-space {
    height:120px;
  }
  .green-space h3 {
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:Myriad Pro;
    color:white;
    background-color:#1F641A;
    text-align:center;
    height:22px;
    line-height:22px;
  }
  .caption {
    position:relative; 
    height:calc(100% - 150px);
    text-align:center;
  }
  .caption .btn{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -45px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail" style="display:inline-block">
                <div class="green-space">
                  <div class="empty-space">
                  </div>
                  <h3>Software Name</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="caption">
                    <p>...</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-ok" role="button">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail" style="display:inline-block">
                <div class="green-space">
                  <div class="empty-space">
                  </div>
                  <h3>Software Name</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="caption">
                    <p>...</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-ok" role="button">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This works okay but now the **square.png** has gotten so much bigger. bigger than the previous **square.png** (as in first `row`)

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using an image to color the thumbnail green?  This could easily be achieved with CSS background colors so that the client doesn't have the network traffic to load a separate png.

Comment: No, this is just a sample I need to test before putting my software. Can I ask you one more question here?

Comment: If it's relevant to the original question, sure.  Otherwise just start a new question :)

Comment: No this is regarding the same above question. this is the question:
**Even if I align them horizontally it lays out a big white space (making a vertical scroll bar considerably long). I have attached a screenshot: imgur.com/a/fMRTs** any help I could have?

Comment: I would need more code to determine what CSS is extending your page.  The easiest way is to hit F12 (developer mode for most browsers) and "inspect" that big white area to see which HTML element is pushing that far down.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<div class="row">` divs and their corresponding end tags. Right now you are forcing them to a seperate "row" by using them, hence the vertical arrangement.

Comment: try resizing your window or use `col-xs-6` instead of sm :)

Answer (score 1):

You created two 'rows'. Instead try this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img alt="..." src="photos/square.png">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3 style="font-size:16px;position:relative;left:35px;top:-27px;font-family:Myriad Pro;color:white;">Software Name</h3>
            <p>...</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-ok" href="#" role="button">Read More</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img alt="..." src="photos/square.png">
        <div class="caption">
            <h3 style="font-size:16px;position:relative;left:35px;top:-27px;font-family:Myriad Pro;color:white;">Software Name</h3>
            <p>...</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-ok" href="#" role="button">Read More</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks work, but My image **square.png** has been resized. It shows in a bigger portion of the screen. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Can you do me a favor and send me a imgur/screenshot?

Comment: Now it is okay. I had to write an inline css for the new position otherwise it looks clumsy as I said :) Thank you very much Sir

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: But one problem sir. Even if I align them horizontally it lays out a big white space (making a vertical scroll bar considerably long). I have attached a screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/fMRTs

Comment: It looks like we were missing a </div> tag. Here's an updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/u9zxs1xL/

Comment: No it works fine with the thumbnails aligned vertically. But I have added this portion of code to the second thumbnail's div in order to align them horizontally as: **<div class="thumbnail" style="position:relative;left:290px;top: -320px;">** and after that here comes the white space

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second row div and the closing div above it and they will be beside each other.

```
<div class="row"> creates a new row
```